# WPショートコード内からデータ構造を出力する方法

Tags: php, wordpress

下記、score.phpの内容をWordPressのショートコード化して固定ページで出力したいと考えております。score.phpは一例ですが、実際のデータは膨大な量の記述があるためにfunctions.phpとは別ファイルとして用意したいと考えております。

**score.php**

```
<?php
  $data = array(
    array(
      'name' => 'player1',
      'time'  => "1分64秒" ),

    array(
      'name' => 'player2',
      'time'  => "1分59秒" )
  );
?>
```

wordpress環境外で検証した結果、下記のソースで出力することはできました。
下記のソースをショートコード化できればと考えています。

```
<?php
  require('score.php');
  foreach($data as $val) { ?>
    <p><?php echo $val['name']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $val['time']; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

拙い説明で申し訳ありませんが、ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようなコードでよろしいかと思います。

```php
<?php
if(!function_exists('score_shortcode')) {
  function score_shortcode($atts, $content) {
    include('score.php');
    $ret = '';
    foreach($data as $val) {
      $ret .= '<p>' . $val['name'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<p>' .
        $val['time'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }
    return $ret;
  }
}
add_shortcode('score', 'score_shortcode');
```

これで`[score]`と記述することでショートコードを記述できると思いますがいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 出力時にデータがエスケープされていないので、元のデータが別途エスケープされていることが保証されていない場合はスクリプトインジェクションが生じます。

Comment: suzukisさんの言う通りです。今回、私は元コードをベースに実装を行ったため、エスケープを行っていません。エスケープを行うには、htmlspecialchars関数を用いる、あるいはWordPress関数のesc_html関数を用います。